# _GUICtrlTreeView_FindItem and _GUICtrlTreeView_ClickItem not working as expected

Tags: eclipse, automation, autoit

I am automating Eclipse IDE in a remote Windows 10 system. I used Windows Remote Desktop in Mac to connect to the Windows system. In this automation I need to search for "QueueManagers" in a SysTreeView32, click it and right-click it.

There is another folder called "QueueManagersClusters" below QueueManagers. When I use RDP through Mac I am able to click "QueueManagers" and right-click it. But when I use RDP through a Lenovo system it clicks "QueueManagersClusters" instead of "QueueManagers":

```
#Region ;**** Directives created by AutoIt3Wrapper_GUI ****
#AutoIt3Wrapper_UseX64=y
#EndRegion ;**** Directives created by AutoIt3Wrapper_GUI ****
#include <GuiTreeView.au3>

WinActivate("eclipse-workspace - Trial/src/module-info.java - Eclipse IDE")
Sleep(1000)

Local $hWnd = ControlGetHandle("eclipse-workspace - Trial/src/module-info.java - Eclipse IDE", "", "SysTreeView321")
;MsgBox(0, "Handle", $hWnd)
Sleep(1000)

Local $searchText = "QueueManagers"
$hItemFound = _GUICtrlTreeView_FindItem($hWnd, $searchText)
;MsgBox(0, "Result", $hItemFound)

If $hItemFound Then
    Sleep(1000)
    _GUICtrlTreeView_ClickItem($hWnd, $hItemFound)
    _GUICtrlTreeView_ClickItem($hWnd, $hItemFound, "right")

    Send("{DOWN}")
    Send("{DOWN}")
    Send("{DOWN}")
EndIf
```

[UI Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aozj8.png)